# Constraints are ignored?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I want to solve a scheduling problem using Pyomo, where no two meetings should be scheduled at the same time. I am using the following constraint in my model to achieve that:

```
model.ID_PAIRS = pyo.Set(initialize = model.ids * model.ids, dimen=2, filter=lambda m, j, k : j < k)
model.disjoint_meetings = gdp.Disjunction(model.ID_PAIRS, rule=lambda model, j, k: [model.start[j] + model.duration[j] <= model.start[k], model.start[k] + model.duration[k] <= model.start[j]])
```

However, this seems to not work correctly, first of all I get a warning: WARNING: Empty constraint block written in LP format - solver may error and secondly, the solution I get is all start values are 0, which should not be possible with non-zero positive durations.

I am looking for two things:

- Why is my code not working?
- How could I have debugged my code to find out myself why it does not work?

Any help will be appreciated :)

My full code is below:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import pyomo.gdp as gdp

# helper function
def add_meeting_data_to_model(model, meetings, slots):
    model.ids = pyo.Set(initialize=meetings.keys(), doc="Meeting IDs")
    dur_dict = { k:meetings[k]['duration'] for k in meetings.keys() }
    model.duration = pyo.Param(model.ids, initialize=dur_dict, doc="Duration of each meeting")
    prio_dict = { k:meetings[k]['prio'] for k in meetings.keys() }
    model.priority = pyo.Param(model.ids, initialize=prio_dict, doc="Priority of each meeting")
    # translate slots (meetings can happen there) into blocks of "non-meeting"
    # which can be scheduled like a meeting, but there start-times are fixed
    # (but the same non-overlap constraints apply between those and meetings)
    no_meeting_start = 0.0
    blocked = {}
    for idx, slot in enumerate(slots):
        no_meeting_end = slot[0]
        name = "allblocked_"+str(idx)
        blocked[name] = {}
        blocked[name]["start"] = no_meeting_start
        blocked[name]["duration"] = no_meeting_end - no_meeting_start
        no_meeting_start = slot[1]
    no_meeting_end = 1.0
    name = "allblocked_"+str(len(slots))
    blocked[name] = {}
    blocked[name]["start"] = no_meeting_start
    blocked[name]["duration"] = no_meeting_end - no_meeting_start
    model.allblocked_ids = pyo.Set(initialize=blocked.keys(), doc="Time block IDs not available for any meeting")
    allblocked_dur_dict = { k:blocked[k]['duration'] for k in blocked.keys() }
    model.allblocked_durations = pyo.Param(model.allblocked_ids, initialize=allblocked_dur_dict, doc="Duration of unavailable blocks for all")
    allblocked_start_dict = { k:blocked[k]['start'] for k in blocked.keys() }
    model.allblocked_start = pyo.Param(model.allblocked_ids, initialize=allblocked_start_dict, doc="Start of unavailable blocks for all")

meetings = {
  0 : {"const" : [],          "duration": 0.3, "prio":1 },
  1 : {"const" : [(0.1,0.2)], "duration": 0.1, "prio":1 },
 }
slots = [(0.3, 0.6)]

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
add_meeting_data_to_model(model, meetings, slots)


model.start = pyo.Var(model.ids, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

model.ID_PAIRS = pyo.Set(initialize = model.ids * model.ids, dimen=2, filter=lambda m, j, k : j < k)
model.disjoint_meetings = gdp.Disjunction(model.ID_PAIRS, rule=lambda model, j, k: [model.start[j] + model.duration[j] <= model.start[k], model.start[k] + model.duration[k] <= model.start[j]])

model.ID_BLOCKED_PAIRS = pyo.Set(initialize = model.ids * model.allblocked_ids, dimen=2)
model.disjoint_meetings = gdp.Disjunction(model.ID_BLOCKED_PAIRS, rule=lambda model, j, k: [model.start[j] + model.duration[j] <= model.allblocked_start[k]] )


model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(expr = sum(model.start[j] for j in model.ids), sense = pyo.minimize)

model.pprint()
opt = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')
opt.solve(model)


for m in model.ids:
    print(str(m) +": "+str(model.start[m]()))
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please, consider reading the guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. This will help you improve the quality of your question and may answer the 2nd part of it.

Comment: this isn't a full answer to your question, and I haven't used disjunctions in pyomo...but did you see the warning that is produced when you run this?  You are making 2 model components with the same name `model.disjoint_meetings` which isn't going to work.  WARNING: Implicitly replacing the Component attribute disjoint_meetings
    (type=<class 'pyomo.gdp.disjunct.IndexedDisjunction'>) on block unknown
    with a new Component (type=<class
    'pyomo.gdp.disjunct.IndexedDisjunction'>). This is usually indicative of a
    modelling error. To avoid this warning....

Comment: @AirSquid thanks, I renamed the second disjoint constraint, but the underlying problem is still there.